# How to mock static method in JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, logback, slf4j

In a unit test in a spring-boot environment with slf4j and logback, I want to make sure `LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()` returns true for a particular test class only.

The reason for that is, that sometimes we have slow and non trivial code guarded with if `(LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {...}`. In a unit test we want to make sure it does not break the application if we switch on trace.

Code under test:

```
public class ClassUnderTest{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class);

    public void doSomething(Calendar gegenwart) {
        if (LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
           // non trivial code
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
public class ClassUnderTestUnitTest{

    @Test
    public void findeSnapshotMitLueke() {
        ClassUnderTest toTestInstance = new ClassUnderTest ();

        // I want to make sure trace logging is enabled, when
        // this method is executed.
        // Trace logging should not be enabled outside this
        // test class.
        toTestInstance.doSomething(Calendar.getInstance());
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? That the non trivial code works, when trace is enabled OR that trace is enabled for only this specific class?

Comment: That the non trivial code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to use a framework like powermock you can do the following trick:

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

    private Supplier<Logger> loggerSupplier = () -> getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class);

    public void doSomething(Calendar gegenwart) {
        if (loggerSupplier.get().isTraceEnabled()) {
           // non trivial code
        }
    }
}
```

Now you are able to mock the logger:

```
public class ClassUnderTestUnitTest{

    @Mock
    private Supplier<Mock> loggerSupplier;
    @Mock
    private Logger logger;

    @Test
    public void findeSnapshotMitLueke() {
        ClassUnderTest toTestInstance = new ClassUnderTest ();

        when(loggerSupplier.get()).thenReturn(logger);
        when(logger.isTraceEnabled()).thenReturn(true)

        toTestInstance.doSomething(Calendar.getInstance());

        // verifyLogger();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a static mock of LoggerFactory using PowerMock and cause it to return a regular mock of Logger (using EasyMock). Then you simply define mock implementation of `Logger.isTraceEnabled()` and `Logger.trace()`.

Off the top of my head:

```java
@PrepareForTest({ LoggerFactory.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // assuming JUnit...
public class ClassUnderTestUnitTest{

    @Test
    public void findeSnapshotMitLueke() {

        Logger mockLogger = EasyMock.createMock(Logger.class);
        EasyMock.expect(mockLogger.isTraceEnabled()).andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect(mockLogger.trace(any()));
        EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes() // as trace is a void method.
        // Repeat for other log methods ...

        PowerMock.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        EasyMock.expect(LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class)
               .andReturn(mockLogger);

        PowerMock.replay(mockLogger, LoggerFactory.class);

        ClassUnderTest toTestInstance = new ClassUnderTest ();

        // I want to make sure trace logging is enabled, when
        // this method is executed.
        // Trace logging should not be enabled outside this
        // test class.
        toTestInstance.doSomething(Calendar.getInstance());

        // After the operation if needed you can verify that the mocked methods were called.
        
        PowerMock.verify(mockLogger).times(...);
        PowerMock.verifyStatic(LoggerFactory.class).times(...);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice solution, if you are ready to introduce 2 new framworks. Guess it would also work with PowerMockito.

Comment: PowerMockito is part of PowerMock actually. PowerMockito is to Mockito what PowerMock is to EasyMock - in both cases you use two frameworks - one for regular mocking and one flavor of PowerMock for the static and final mocking. But the bottom line is you need to use a flavor of PowerMock to achieve the result that Chris311 is after.

Comment: On a side note - while Mockito is easier to use in my experience it's creating too many opportunities for false positives because it creates nice mocks by default. EasyMock is explicit about the type of mocks created and doesn't hide bugs behind a null-returning unmocked method.